# Baking Models with AO

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking

Recently I have been working on an aircraft that has been a little project of mine, and I have wanted to bake the AO onto it.

[image: Here is what it looks like]

[image: Here is what i want it to look like]

The first picture is what happens when I bake it. While the second one is what I want it to look like. As you can see there is a weird black spot and to the right of it a spot that is darker then it should be. The same with the nacelle under it, the nacelle appears slightly darker then it should be. The bottom picture is of the aircraft with the viewing AO in the shading menu, I just want what I see in the shading menu to be perfectly put onto my UV map.

Comment: A few things could cause this, from a bad UV unwrapping job to duplicate vertices and inverted normals.

Comment: If you're still looking for an answer, is it possible you could upload part of your .blend? (just the enough to demonstrate the issue)

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with HATMAN - Possibly inverted Normals or doubles. Go into *Edit mode*, Press <kbd>W</kbd> - *Remove doubles* (also available from the tool menu on the LH side). Along the bottom menu, you can also recalculate normals by going to *mesh> normals>recalculate outside* . They should help.

When you do these, take note of the top bar (where it says the amount of tris etc), and it will tell you if it had to remove doubles etc..

Comment: I just did that and although it did remove the doubles, the texture now doesn't show the spot as black, which is good, it shows it with an AO baked object, that part of the object still appears black even though the texture is not, and it is not a problem with the UV mapped because it has been UV unwrapped by a pro and has been textured many times.

Comment: @JordanPalmer Are there any overlapping UVs? Often different parts of a model are mapped to the same spot in order to re-use parts of the texture, however this doesn't work with baking. If the UV professional didn't think the map would be used for baking, it's possible..